# Can I compare two datetime.datetime fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am having two-time fields - one from the database and one is the current time. I want to check if the current time is greater than the database time field or lesser. How to do that?

```
if expiration_date < datetime.now():
    item_info['expired'] = True
```

can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: Use `timezone.now()`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Comment: No, it was not working. I used the below answer by replacing datetime.datetime.now to datetime.now. It's working now.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing two different datetime types and hence the problem.By default, the datetime object is naive in Python, and the other value is aware here.

```
if expiration_date < datetime.datetime.now(expiration_date.tzinfo):
   item_info['expired'] = True
```

Since you asked the question for Django, you could also use [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/).

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

if expiration_date < timezone.now():
   item_info['expired'] = True
```

Comment: It's working now but I had to replace datetime.datetime.now to datetime.now from your answer.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please consider accepting and upvoting the answer to keep the SO circle intact, thanks :)